# Why Application.OnException never runs?

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

**Problem summary:** The method assigned to `Application.OnException` never runs when an unhandled exception occurs.

I create a blank project with only this unit and place a single button on `Unit.dfm` (this is based on an [official example](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_OnException.html)) :

```
// Unit1.pas
// *********

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AppException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Application.OnException := AppException;
end;

procedure TForm1.AppException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
    Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    raise Exception.Create('Incorrect password entered');
end;
```

Then I set a breakpoint inside `TForm1.AppException()`. I run the program, click the button, an error dialog is shown saying "Incorrect password entered" but if I continue execution the breakpoint never breaks; the program doesn't `Terminate` like I asked it too. The program continues running and I can press the button again.

I tried the same code (adapted) in Delphi 7 but the same result is encountered.

Comment: Works just fine here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for trying the code. Do have any ideas how I could debug why it's not happening for me?

Comment: Is your FormCreate event handler disconnected from your form's OnCreate event? See in the Object Inspector, or the form's .dfm.

Comment: No idea. I'd put `Caption := 'Boo';` in `AppException`. Perhaps the code runs but debugging is broken. But perhaps FormCreate is not running.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I put `Button1.Caption := 'Boo';` in there, but the button caption didn't change, sadly.

Comment: Does FormCreate execute

Comment: @TOndrej Oh hmm the Object Inspector says `Form1.OnCreate` points to `nil`, and the debugger never hits the breakpoint inside `FormCreate`. I thought I was overriding the `FormCreate` method inherent to `TForm` objects.

Comment: No, you don't override `FormCreate` - it's an event handler for `TForm.OnCreate`. `FormCreate` is not a part of `TForm` - it's a part of your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only rational explanation is the `FormCreate` is not executing. You need to assign it to the form's `OnCreate` event handler. Use the object inspector to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a third party exception handler such as madExcept, Application.OnException will no longer fire. You must instead follow the third party's advice. For madExcept you must code TMadExceptionHandler.OnException event or directly call RegisterExceptionHandler.